# Chart.js dataset controller 'null' when chart drawn

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, performance, chart.js

Let me apologize in advance. I'm not a javascript/web developer and I don't even claim to have a working knowledge of the language or a good grasp of the environment. I'm an embedded C/C++ programmer and I literally have only learned enough JS to try to get this one little side project done, but now I'm stuck on a bug that seems to have put me well out of my depth.

I'm trying to write a graphing utility that I can plug JSON-formatted, by-date performance data into to give me a historical view of performance tied to our nightly builds/CI tests; the goal being to identify at a glance any regressions in performance from day to day. I've attempted to take the chart.js line.html sample and modified it to fit my needs. It mostly works, except that when the page initially loads, the chart is blank. However, when I open the javascript console to debug, then it draws/functions correctly, but I see this error:
**Chart.bundle.min.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'draw' of null(anonymous function)**

When I look at my config data for the chart, the data in the datasets is correct, however, the 'controller' object in the _meta field of the datasets is null, which I believe is what causes the error. I'm not sure what to do about this. Perhaps I didn't fully satisfy the requirements of initializing the dataset object, but I think that I have done everything that the sample did. I wonder if perhaps I overwrote some part of the object inadvertently or if this is just a sequencing thing? I'm lost.

**EDIT:** I've just realized that any resize of the window causes the chart to be drawn correctly. I think that opening the javascript console made it work purely due to the resize of the main window. When I dump the config data in the console after the resize, _meta.controller property is no longer null. Perhaps I have some sequencing messed up or need to delay something, but this seems like a big clue. It seems to function 100% correctly after a resize of the window. I still don't know where to go from here though.

Here's the code:

```
<title>Line Chart</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" charset=UTF-8></script>
<script src="Chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<style>
canvas{
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}
</style>
```

close head and open body tags here - seems to mess up the code textbox

```
<div style="width:75%;">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<script>
    var randomColorFactor = function() {
        return Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    };
    var randomColor = function(opacity) {
        return 'rgba(' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + randomColorFactor() + ',' + (opacity || '.3') + ')';
    };
    var get_json_data= function(){

      var my_labels = [], my_data = [];
      $.getJSON("perf_data.json", function(json){
      var insert_dataset = {'label': "Insert Performance", 'hidden': false, 'data': [], 'fill': true, 'borderDash': [5,5],
                            'borderColor': randomColor(0.4), 'backgroundColor': randomColor(0.5), 'pointBorderColor': randomColor(0.7),
                            'pointBackgroundColor': randomColor(0.5), 'pointBorderWidth': 1};
      var verify_dataset = {'label': "Verify Performance", 'hidden': false, 'data': [], 'fill': true, 'borderDash': [5,5],
                            'borderColor': randomColor(0.4), 'backgroundColor': randomColor(0.5), 'pointBorderColor': randomColor(0.7),
                            'pointBackgroundColor': randomColor(0.5), 'pointBorderWidth': 1};
      var update_dataset = {'label': "Update Performance", 'hidden': false, 'data': [], 'fill': true, 'borderDash': [5,5],
                            'borderColor': randomColor(0.4), 'backgroundColor': randomColor(0.5), 'pointBorderColor': randomColor(0.7),
                            'pointBackgroundColor': randomColor(0.5), 'pointBorderWidth': 1};
      var delete_dataset = {'label': "Delete Performance", 'hidden': false, 'data': [], 'fill': true, 'borderDash': [5,5],
                            'borderColor': randomColor(0.4), 'backgroundColor': randomColor(0.5), 'pointBorderColor': randomColor(0.7),
                            'pointBackgroundColor': randomColor(0.5), 'pointBorderWidth': 1};

      $.each(json, function (i, date_data) {
          //console.log(date_data);
          my_labels.push(date_data.datestamp);
          $.each(date_data.data, function(j, workload) {
            if (workload['op'] == "insert") {
              insert_dataset.data.push(parseFloat(workload.iops));
            } else if (workload['op'] == "verify" ) {
              verify_dataset.data.push(parseFloat(workload.iops));
            } else if (workload['op'] == "update" ) {
              update_dataset.data.push(parseFloat(workload.iops));
            } else if (workload['op'] == "delete" ) {
              delete_dataset.data.push(parseFloat(workload.iops));
           } else {
              console.log("Scomething went wrong w/ the data parsing.");
            }
          });
        });
        my_data.push(insert_dataset);
        my_data.push(verify_dataset);
        my_data.push(update_dataset);
        my_data.push(delete_dataset);
      })
    .fail(function (d, textStatus, error) {
      console.error("getJSON failed, status: " + textStatus + ", error: "+error)
      });
      return { "labels": my_labels , "datasets": my_data }; 
    };

    config = {};
    config['type'] = "line";
    config['data'] = get_json_data();
    config['options'] = {
            'responsive': true,
            'title':{
                'display':true,
                'text':'TOAD BVT performance'
            },
            'tooltips': {
                'mode': 'label',
                'callbacks': {
                    // beforeTitle: function() {
                    //     return '...beforeTitle';
                    // },
                    // afterTitle: function() {
                    //     return '...afterTitle';
                    // },
                    // beforeBody: function() {
                    //     return '...beforeBody';
                    // },
                    // afterBody: function() {
                    //     return '...afterBody';
                    // },
                    // beforeFooter: function() {
                    //     return '...beforeFooter';
                    // },
                    // footer: function() {
                    //     return 'Footer';
                    // },
                    // afterFooter: function() {
                    //     return '...afterFooter';
                    // },
                }
            }
          };
    config['hover'] = { 'mode': 'dataset' };
    config['scales'] = {
                'xAxes': [{
                    'display': true,
                    'scaleLabel': {
                        'show': true,
                        'labelString': 'Date'
                    }
                }],
                'yAxes': [{
                    'display': true,
                    'scaleLabel': {
                        'show': true,
                        'labelString': 'IOPS'
                    },
                    'ticks': {
                        'suggestedMin': 0,
                        'suggestedMax': 5000000
                    }
                }]
            };

    window.onload = function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
    };

</script>
```

And here is my sample of my JSON input file:

```
[
{
  "datestamp":"01/01/16",
   "data":[
      {"op":"insert", "iops":"83934.51429194942"},
      {"op":"verify", "iops":"15439.723320158104"},
      {"op":"update", "iops":"53198.20988023753"},
      {"op":"delete", "iops":"47994.31747281122"}
    ]
},
{
  "datestamp":"01/02/16",
  "data":[
      {"op":"insert", "iops":"84934.51429194942"},
      {"op":"verify", "iops":"14439.723320158104"},
      {"op":"update", "iops":"54198.20988023753"},
      {"op":"delete", "iops":"44994.31747281122"}
  ]
}
]
```

Any help or ideas are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try wrapping the code inside the window.load function inside a delay using setTimeout, if it works then your assumption might be right, i.e the draw function is getting triggered before the context exists. There are workarounds for that!

Comment: Good idea. Thanks. I still see the error pop up after 3 seconds (my timeout value), so the problem seems related to sequencing more than timing. It turns out that the null _meta.controller object and not drawing until screen resize were 2 different issues. I've solved the screen resize issue in a round about way by using bootstrap tabs with a chart on each tab for my different machine configurations and setting the <div class= "tab-pane fade in"> for each tab with a chart on it. If i set 'active' in the class field, the charts don't draw correctly until resize, but without it they draw right.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle out of this! Would love to debug.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, but I'll look into it. :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qomrs4qp/2/ - so when I was creating the fiddle, I didn't have the input files available, which caused me to restructure some of the variable declarations in get_json_data and wouldn't you know it, the error disappeared. I didn't figure out the exact root cause, but things are working better now. My only remaining issue is that the chart on the first/active tab still doesn't draw on load. I have to resize or force some other update of the tab before the data gets drawn on the chart. Feel free to play with it.

Comment: I was able to replicate the fix for the null controller in my local version that pulls the json data from file by implementing the same restructuring in get_json_data, so there's something that I'm not understanding about variable scope in javascript or something along those lines. The fiddle linked above just dummies up some data since I didn't want to take the time to upload and link to the real json files.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case. I used the configuration in the first js file, and the code that creates the chart in the second js file. After drawing the chart, I got an error: "controller is null". I solved the problem by deep copying through the "extend" method (but I used JQuery).
default constructor in first file:

```
const standart_chart = {
  type: 'bar',
  options: {}, 
  ...
}
```

adding data and create chart in the second file:

```
var ctx = $('#chart');
var chart = jQuery.extend(true, {}, standart_chart);
chart.data = barChartData;

var chart_obj = new Chart(ctx, chart);
```